# Send to python-shell-interpreter from the project root

Tags: python, compile-mode, python-lsp-server

How can I tell the shell to always open relative to my project root?

I have the following python project structure:

```
mypyjunk
├── mypyjunk
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── jitter.py
├── README.md
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_all.py
```

And `mypyjunk/jitter.py` contains:

```
from mypyjunk.common import constants


def do_things():
    print(constants)
```

When I open this file and open a shell interpreter with `C-c C-p`, I try to send the buffer to the interpreter with `C-c C-r`, it says:

```
>>> from mypyjunk.common import constants
... 
... 
... def do_things():
...     print(constants)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in __PYTHON_EL_eval
  File "/home/user/mypyjunk/mypyjunk/jitter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mypyjunk.common import constants
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypyjunk'
```

Which tells me this shell has an unexpected root directory, eg:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/user/mypyjunk/mypyjunk'
```

Instead of `/home/user/mypyjunk/` where my absolute imports would make sense.

What settings do I need to change to tell python-mode or compile-mode to respect the project root?  Also, assume I have lots of projects in `~/` so I can't hard-code a path here in my `.emacs.d/init.el`, without potentially clobbering my other projects.

Comment: Can you change the working directory of the buffer where the interpreter is running with `M-x cd`? If that works, then something might be done through a hook or an advice or some other Emacs means...

Comment: This doesn’t change the results of ‘os.getcwd()’ which remain in the original directory

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a 'nicer' way using already existing stuff in `python.el`, but if you just want the interpreter to start at the project root while you're within that project, I'd do something like:

```lisp
(defvar-local my-python-dir-override nil)

(defun my-run-python ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory (or my-python-dir-override default-directory)))
    (call-interactively #'run-python)))
```

Then set `my-python-dir-override` in your `.dir-locals.el` in the project root directory, and bind `C-c C-p` to `my-run-python`.

If you don't want to use `.dir-locals.el`, you could swap out `my-python-dir-override` for `(projectile-project-root)` (if you're a projectile user) or `(project-root)`, though this logic will then apply to all projects.

Comment: Very nice. This is the sort of answer that I was really struggling to find. Concise, descriptive code that really solves the problem and doesn't introduce lots of sys imports etc. I'm surprised that this hasn't been a problem for more people. Personally, I would structure the answer the other way around as the project-root advice solves the general problem and any mention of dir-locals, rightly or wrongly, tends to make think it's a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Importing modules is explained [in this document](https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/).
For your case, in `jitter.py` write `from . common import constants`
(you can use full name for `common`)

EDIT:
The specified document treat also the case for absolute path - you may use
`sys.path and sys.append`.
Other solution(s) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder), see Nagev's response or use the [importlib module](https://realpython.com/python-import/#using-importlib).

Comment: I’m working in a codebase that requires absolute imports instead of relative ones and this cannot be changed.